# python if-statement and boolean(how to combine two functions into one)

Tags: python, if-statement, sqlite, boolean

I 've written two function for each table to receive field's command. And my teammate needs me to remix two function into one. Finally I make this function but it cannot receive my router table 's command.
this is my two functions:

```
# def readrouter(x):
#         conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
#         cur = conn.cursor()
#         cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT command FROM router WHERE   function =? or function='configure terminal' or function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",(x,))
#         read = cur.fetchall()
#         return read;
#
# a = input("x:")
# for result in readrouter(a):
#     print (result[0])

# def readswitch(x):
#         conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
#         cur = conn.cursor()
#         cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or function='configure terminal' or function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",(x,))
#         read = cur.fetchall()
#         return read;
# a = input("x:")
# for result in readrouter(a):
#     print (result[0])
```

This is my function after combine two function into one:

```
def readciscodevice(x):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        if x:
                cur.execute(
                        "SELECT DISTINCT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or function='configure terminal' or function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",
                        (x,))
                read = cur.fetchall()
                return read
        else:
                cur.execute(
                        "SELECT DISTINCT command FROM router WHERE   function =? or function='configure terminal' or function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",
                        (x,))
                read = cur.fetchall()
                return read;


a = raw_input("x:")
for result in readciscodevice(a):
        print(result[0])
```

I use my if-statement and it can read my switch table 's command but cannot get commands from switch table. Do I need to write boolean or something else to ensure that it can access my router table?

Update(I am trying to select two commands first which is enable and conf t, then I am going to identify my inputs,if the input is matched to my switch 's field "function", it provide some commands, ELSE going to match my router's field "function"):

```
# def readciscodevice(x):
#         conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
#         cur = conn.cursor()
#
#         cur.execute(
#                         "SELECT DISTINCT command FROM switch WHERE   function='configure terminal' or function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC"
#         )
#
#         if x:
#                 cur.execute(
#                         "SELECT DISTINCT command FROM switch WHERE   function =?  ORDER BY key ASC",
#                         (x,))
#                 read = cur.fetchall()
#                 return read
#         else:
#                 cur.execute(
#                         "SELECT DISTINCT command FROM router WHERE   function =?   ORDER BY key ASC",
#                         (x,))
#                 read = cur.fetchall()
#                 return read;
#
#
# a = raw_input("x:")
# for result in readciscodevice(a):
#         print(result[0])
```

In the updates code:
It cannot select enable conf t commands
Also cannot reach to my router 's field to get commands..
but it can select switch commands

Comment: What is your example input in `a = raw_input("x:")`?

Comment: @Marcin I will input my function 'no rip' then it outputs enable ,configure terminal, no network (network address) , no router rip

Comment: your conditions ` if x:` imply that you check only for not false variables. string `no rip` is not empty and your else never executes. Difficult to understand how do you want to use `a` in the conditions with`x`.

Comment: @Marcin Sorry for my mistakes from x. Honestly I am not really understand how to use if x:.Is the problem maybe exist in select switch table's statement as I must draw two command in my first select statement. I have update my code but not work but hope u know what i wanna do!

Comment: @Marcin As my teammate has my table with excel. I dun think he will input false varable into the raw_input, so  I did not try to make empty value in my if statement, should i do more for the empty value or wrong error in my statement? But we only want to output command but not something like "you input is empty!" or "your input is error!"

Comment: Can you provide examples of inputs `a = raw_input("x:")` and what is their effect. If you enter e.g. "no rip" than which conditions should execute. And when you enter something else, what other condition should execute.

Comment: @Marcin if I intput 0, some words not in my table it outputs enable, configure terminal . if i input words in switch table, like "create vlan" it outputs enable ,configure terminal,vlan (VLAN IDs) ,name (vlan name). If i input words in router table like no passive-interface fa, it cannot work and printout enable,configure terminal

Comment: @Marcin sorry maybe i did not tag your name in last comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either introduce another argument to determine which block you wish to execute or have a clear distinction between two conditions of x. 
'If x:' just checks that x has a valid (non falsey) value, so things with empty values will fail like: 0, None, false, '', etc.

Comment: So if user input 0 ,or error input ,should i write a if-statement to return false and re-run my function? But now I cannot access my router 's table to get commands too. Do u know what I mean in my new update? As i think one of the problem is when i wanna select command from router's field .It access switch table first ,it only select enable and conf t command. As it selected commands from switch so my function is ended. But actually what i wanna select is in router's field

Comment: Its hard to understand what you're trying to do, but you are correct in that only the switch condition will he met, every time the user inputs a nonempty string. You need to check the users input. Like you could do if x == "router" or x== "switch". If x holds some other critical data you could have a second argument, maybe call it switch and make it a boolean. Then the if condition could check 'if switch'

Comment: thank you so much ! I have added a parameter to determine with if y == "switch": and elif y == "router": Finally i can draw command in router table too